# Coded UI: How to retry right clicking on a context menu to check for an enabled option

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automate a process in one of my Coded UI tests where I right click on a cell in a table and if the 'Paste' button is enabled I want to select it.

However this button is only enabled if there is something to 'Paste', which is not always the case. So I want to right click and check if 'Paste' is enabled. If not, wait 10 seconds and try again and maybe keep doing this up to 10 times, then fail. The best i've come up with so far a process where I right click on the cell, if the Paste button is not enabled, wait 10 seconds and try again..

```
Mouse.Click(Cell1, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(125, 10));
while (!PasteButton.Enabled)
    {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Mouse.Click(Cell1, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(125, 10));
    if (PasteButton.Enabled)
    {
        Mouse.Click(Cell1, new Point(54, 12));
    }
}
```

I'm aware of something like

```
PasteButton.WaitForControlPropertyEqual(PasteButton.Value, "Paste", 60000);
```

But I can't right click and wait for the button to become enabled as it doesn't auto refresh. So I need to keep checking by right clicking on the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MPavlak, your solution pointed me in the right direction. I had to make a few adjustments to your pseudo code to make it work for my application.

Visual Studio insisted that I declare var rightClickCell = () as rightClickCell = new Action(() = > etc...

WinContextMenu was actually a WinList, WinMenuItem turned out to be a Winbutton in that list in our application.

I used SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] instead of SearchProperties.Add as its consistent with the way i've discovered other objects in application.

I had to add a Click on the main cell within the while loop, as right clicking on the same spot in the cell wasn't actually refreshing the menu. In rightClickCell I could change new Point(125, 10) into new Point(x,y) and possibly decrement the x value each time it goes through the while loop, thus moving the right point to a different position. But thats more lines of code, where left clicking on the cell before the right click produces the same result.

WaitForControlEnabled wasn't found, so caused an exception, so I used Thread.Sleep.

```
var rightClickCell = new Action(() => Mouse.Click(cell1, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(125, 10)));
var contextMenu = new WinList(uIContextMenu);
var pasteMenuItem = new WinButton(contextMenu);
pasteMenuItem.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "Paste";

rightClickCell();
while (!pasteMenuItem.TryFind() || !pasteMenuItem.Enabled)
{
    Mouse.Click(cell1, new Point(10, 10));
    rightClickCell();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

if (pasteMenuItem.Enabled)
{
    pasteMenuItem.DrawHighlight();
    Mouse.Click(pasteMenuItem, new Point(10, 10));
}
```

If I try to define rightClickCell with an x,y value I get the error: 
Delete 'Action does not take 0 arguments'.

```
var rightClickCell = new Action(() => Mouse.Click(cell1, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(int x, int y)));
```

Comment: I wouldn't move the point for the click, but instead focus onto something else to get the context menu to disappear completely.  Glad I could get you at least part way there.

Comment: Well then i'd move the right click point by passing in an x and y value for the click and decrement the x mark so the menu appears in a slightly different spot. However I get an error when I try and define the 'rightclickcell()' with an x and y value. I've updated the above 'Answer' with my code.

Comment: I still wouldn't move the point and do a click.  Find something else on the page and focus on it so that the menu disappears and you can right click back in the same spot.

Comment: var rightClickCell = new Action((x, y) => Mouse.Click(cell1, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(x, y)));

Answer (score 1):

How does something get into the clipboard for you to paste if you are not taking an action other than right clicking?  If you have a way to test for that, you could improve your check, but otherwise, it seems like what you are doing is correct.  I would slightly alter the code though.

```
var rightClickCell = () => Mouse.Click(Cell1, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(125, 10));

rightClickCell();
while (!PasteButton.Enabled);
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    rightClickCell();
}

if (PasteButton.Enabled)
{
    // PROBABLY DO NOT WHAT TO DO THIS
    // instead, find the context menu and click the item
    // whose name/text is "Paste"
    Mouse.Click(Cell1, new Point(54, 12));
}
```

Even better, maybe something more like this:

```
var rightClickCell = () => Mouse.Click(Cell1, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(125, 10));

// pseudo code
var contextMenu = new WinContextMenu(Cell1);
var pasteMenuItem = new WinMenuItem(contextMenu);
pasteMenuItem.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Paste");

rightClickCell();
while(!pasteMenuItem.TryFind() || !pasteMenuItem.Enabled)
{
   rightClickCell();
   WaitForControlEnabled(pasteMenuItem, 10 * 1000);
}

if(pasteMenuItem.Enabled)
{
   Mouse.Click(pasteMenuItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your 2nd option 90% works. Visual Studio wanted me to do a few things differently. This is the working version.